# Cannot clone git repository in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, repository, bitbucket

My System is Windows 10. I downloaded git.  I just started to use bitbucket with Eclipse. When I tried to clone a git repository, I got this error. I set sslVerify to "false". Also I am sure the URL is correct. I don't know what I can try else.

[image]

[This is error log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvznL.png)

Comment: What details are shown in the Error Log?

Comment: What is the _exact_ URL you're using? This works fine for both a public and private repository when I try it.

Comment: I solved it with adding eclipse rsa to bitbucket. Thank you for attention

Comment: @EminÇiftçi that sounds like you have a great solution to a problem, Can you write it up as a [solution and accept your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?